# The non-abstract class 'CustomCanvas' is missing implementations for these members

Tags: flutter, dart, implementation, flutter-canvas, flutter-pubspec

I am using flutter_smartlook for monitoring in my app. It was working fine, But after upgrading to the latest version 4.1.7. It started to cause an error while running. If I downgrade to 4.1.5. It was working fine. Can anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

To use the latest Flutter version 3.13.0, I have no otherchoice but to upgrade the package to 4.1.7. Or do I have to use the old Flutter version 3.10.6

**Error:**

```
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.7/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/canvas_descriptor.dart:7:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'CustomCanvas' is
missing implementations for these members:
 - Canvas.clipPath
 - Canvas.clipRRect
 - Canvas.clipRect
 - Canvas.drawAtlas
 - Canvas.drawColor
 - Canvas.drawDRRect
 - Canvas.drawImage
 - Canvas.drawImageNine
 - Canvas.drawImageRect
 - Canvas.drawOval
 - Canvas.drawPaint
 - Canvas.drawParagraph
 - Canvas.drawPicture
 - Canvas.drawPoints
 - Canvas.drawRRect
 - Canvas.drawRawAtlas
 - Canvas.drawRawPoints
 - Canvas.drawShadow
 - Canvas.drawVertices
 - Canvas.getDestinationClipBounds
 - Canvas.getLocalClipBounds
 - Canvas.getSaveCount
 - Canvas.getTransform
 - Canvas.restore
 - Canvas.restoreToCount
 - Canvas.rotate
 - Canvas.save
 - Canvas.saveLayer
 - Canvas.scale
 - Canvas.skew
 - Canvas.transform
 - Canvas.translate
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class CustomCanvas extends Canvas {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.clipPath' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.clipRRect' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.clipRect' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawAtlas' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawColor' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawDRRect' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawImage' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawImageNine' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawImageRect' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawOval' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawPaint' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawParagraph' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawPicture' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawPoints' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawRRect' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawRawAtlas' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawRawPoints' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawShadow' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.drawVertices' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.getDestinationClipBounds' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.getLocalClipBounds' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.getSaveCount' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.getTransform' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.restore' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.restoreToCount' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.rotate' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.save' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.saveLayer' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.scale' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.skew' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.transform' is defined here.
org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/ui/canvas.dart: Context: 'Canvas.translate' is defined here.
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_google_places_sdk-0.3.2+9/lib/flutter_google_places_sdk.dart:123:55: Error: Member not found: 'ALL'.
    PlaceTypeFilter placeTypeFilter = PlaceTypeFilter.ALL,
                                                      ^^^
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_google_places_sdk-0.3.2+9/lib/flutter_google_places_sdk.dart:132:11: Error: No named parameter with the name
'placeTypeFilter'.
          placeTypeFilter: placeTypeFilter,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.7/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/canvas_descriptor.dart:13:7: Error: Superclass has no constructor named
'Canvas'.
  ) : super(recorder);
      ^^^^^
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.7/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/canvas_descriptor.dart:17:11: Error: Superclass has no method named
'drawRect'.
    super.drawRect(rect, paint);
          ^^^^^^^^
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.7/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/canvas_descriptor.dart:27:11: Error: Superclass has no method named
'drawCircle'.
    super.drawCircle(c, radius, paint);
          ^^^^^^^^^^
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.7/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/canvas_descriptor.dart:39:11: Error: Superclass has no method named
'drawArc'.
    super.drawArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, useCenter, paint);
          ^^^^^^^
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.7/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/canvas_descriptor.dart:45:11: Error: Superclass has no method named
'drawPath'.
    super.drawPath(path, paint);
          ^^^^^^^^
/Users/casperonflutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_smartlook-4.1.7/lib/wireframe/element_descriptors/canvas_descriptor.dart:65:11: Error: Superclass has no method named
'drawLine'.
    super.drawLine(p1, p2, paint);
          ^^^^^^^^
Unhandled exception:
Null check operator used on a null value
#0      ProgramCompiler._emitSuperConstructorCallIfNeeded (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1962:47)
#1      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructorBody (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1901:19)
#2      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructor.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1848:19)
#3      ProgramCompiler._superDisallowed (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:4107:24)
#4      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructor.<anonymous closure> (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1847:15)
#5      ProgramCompiler._withLetScope (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:2693:25)
#6      ProgramCompiler._withCurrentFunction (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:4097:18)
#7      ProgramCompiler._emitConstructor (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1845:16)
#8      ProgramCompiler._defineConstructors (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:1459:28)
#9      ProgramCompiler._emitClassDeclaration (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:879:19)
#10     ProgramCompiler._emitClass (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:802:25)
#11     List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:416:8)
#12     ProgramCompiler._emitLibrary (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:740:23)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got a reply from smartlook's support. Posting here their response:

"Currently, the only version of our SDK that does work with 3.12.x version of flutter is the prerelease https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smartlook/versions/4.1.8-flutter3.13.0. Please use that one, you should not face this issue, let me know if you have any further questions."

Answer (score 1):

They messing up a bit with the releases, now a new version 4.18 is out but it does NOT supoport flutter 13, so if you defined your dependency in the manifest with the caret symbol

```yaml
flutter_smartlook: ^4.1.8-flutter3.13.0
```

it will NOT work, you need to stick to the exact version by removing the caret:

```yaml
flutter_smartlook: 4.1.8-flutter3.13.0
```

I hope they'll soon merge flutter 13 changes to the main branch, it's been out for months now.